# How to safely change the unique key with Entitiy Framework - Database First

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a table with some component data where I have added and auto-generated Id as the primary key. But the component has a unique property, and I would like to switch to use that and delete the autogenerated column. The unique property has no "Id" in it's name for EF to be recognized automatically. Is it safe to simply delete the auto-generated column, and set the unique property as the primary key? How can I tell EF to take the unique property as the primery key without adding "Id" into the column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update your model from the database, EF looks for the primary key and uses that - it does not matter what you name the column. (there is no logic in EF that looks for a column with "id" in the name)

So you'll be fine. Update your database, then update EF from your database and it should pick up on the change.